# redirect uri causing issues when navigating to an oauth url

Tags: swift, oauth-2.0, nsurl

I am trying to navigate to the [Microsoft Live oauth authentication](https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/msa_oauth.htm#code-flow) page so that I can authorize my user and get a token for use by the app. When I use the following `NSURL` string, I am able to navigate to the site and authorize my app, retrieving the token.

```
let stringUrl = "https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=\(clientId)&scope=\(scope)&response_type=code"
let url = NSURL(string: stringUrl)!
```

However, I want to redirect back to my app (using `SFSafariViewController`). In order to do so, I added a URL Scheme to my app, and passed that in as the redirect_uri in the URL.

```
let stringUrl = "https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=\(clientId)&scope=\(scope)&response_type=code&redirect_uri=Lifestream://onedrive-oauth-callback"
let url = NSURL(string: stringUrl)!
```

[image: info.plist file]

However the Live login site gives me an error saying something went wrong and it couldn't continue. This error occurs before the oauth login page is displayed. It happens immediately upon navigating to the URL.

Am I creating my URL scheme incorrectly, or passing the scheme in to the redirect uri improperly? I'm confused as to why it works fine without the redirect_uri, but the site can't load when I provide it.

[image: Redirect issue]

Can someone point me in the right direction on how I am supposed to pass a redirect url for my app, into an oauth redirect?

**Update**

It seems that Microsoft does not allow you to register a redirect URL that is a App URL scheme. I dont know how to get this info back into my app then, other than just paying for a site I can point MSFT to, which would then do nothing but redirects into the app for me.

[image: MSFT limitation]

Comment: To me this sounds like Microsoft doesn't recognize your redirect URI. Have you registered that redirect URI with Microsoft? The OAuth 2 spec says that if the redirect URI isn't recognized, the auth flow is supposed to halt and the AP displays a failure message ([see section 4.1.2.1](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.1.2.1)). I haven't used Microsoft's OAuth service before (nor App URL schemes), so I can't offer any other advice if Microsoft doesn't let you register your custom URI as a redirect URI.

Comment: Note that unrecognized Redirect URIs (and client IDs, obviously) are somewhat unique verification failures in that they are the only two conditions that don't allow an error to be sent to your Redirect Endpoint. Normally you get back an error code if something goes wrong, and your client app can decide how to handle it. Since the OAuth provider can't verify the redirect URI, it makes sense for them not to send error info to it, as that would potentially allow for a third party to switch the redirect URI for malicious purposes.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look and see if I can register it. If not, I'll have to look at how other people handle these kind of things with oauth and app URL schemes

Comment: After looking in my Microsoft settings, it does indeed look like they dont support App URL schemes. I updated my OP with a screenshot of it. I'll have to figure something else out then

Comment: This is an educated guess on my part, but I would guess the way to go would be register a web server as your Redirect Endpoint, and have it accept the redirects and translate them to your custom URLs. I feel that that is an inadequate description, but it's late and that's the best I can do right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar OAuth problem and didn't want to mess around with a web server so instead what I did was kinda cheeky. Make a UIWebView and put the request on the web view. Then delegate it to yourself and pass the redirect URL to be http://localhost:8000 (it can be anything like that it really doesn't matter). Then inside the delegate do this:

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool
{
    if let URL = request.URL?.absoluteString
    {
        // This should be the redirect URL that you pass it can be anything like local host mentioned above.
        if URL.hasPrefix(redirectURL) 
        {
            // Now you can simply do some string manipulation to pull out the relevant components.
            // I'm not sure what sort of token or how you get it back but assuming the redirect URL is 
            // YourRedirectURL&code=ACCESS_TOKEN and you want access token heres how you would get it.
            var code : String?
            if let URLParams = request.URL?.query?.componentsSeparatedByString("&")
            {
                for param in URLParams
                {
                    let keyValue = param.componentsSeparatedByString("=")
                    let key = keyValue.first
                    if key == "code"
                    {
                        code = keyValue.last
                    }
                }
            }
            // Here if code != nil then it has the ACCESS_TOKEN and you are done! If its nil something went wrong.
            return false // So that the webview doesnt redirect to the dummy URL you passed.
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

This is sorta hacky but it works great and you don't need any server nor do you need a redirect URI on your app, its an awesome way to do it in my opinion. You could optimize this for swift 2 to reduce the indentation by using guards but I wrote this before it came out so...

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'll give this a shot. At the moment I am using the new `SFSafariViewController` which doesn't let you handle the request callbacks. I'll pull that component out and try to get a web view built out and try this.

Comment: Ahh but that would only work with iOS 9 this solution can be used for any version, plus it works like SFSafariViewController in that it keeps the user in your app at all times. I used this for the Uber API cause I didn't want to setup the a redirect URI for my iOS app and this worked great. Let me know if you run into any issues, just make sure you change the string manipulation to suit your needs. Not sure how Microsoft returns the token.

Comment: This strikes me as unsafe. The whole point of registering a Redirect URI is so that tokens can only be sent back to your registered server. If you are registering localhost, what would stop me from using your Client ID outside of your app and harvesting tokens?

Comment: You are only registering localhost with Microsoft as the redirect URL, you immediately catch when Microsoft is redirecting to local host and stop it from occurring. Plus this is inside a UIWebView inside the sandboxed app so its completely safe cause no outside application has access to it. You don't need to use localhost that was just an example, you can use literally any URL including http://google.com. The whole idea is to intercept the redirect from inside the app and process the redirect URL plus you return false so that redirect is never actually called.

Comment: This worked well, I was able to intercept the redirect and grab my token code. Thanks for the help.